# Using Modal Dialogs in Internet Explorer with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and have figured out how to use it to create and navigate with an Internet Explorer Application Object.  I am also capable of manipulating inputs and clicking buttons, but I have run into an issue with manipulating modal dialogs that come up on websites (like an error message or a file download confirmation)  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something from MSDN that discusses this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309183.aspx).  Instead of using powershell, it was the same deal, but using a C# class to run the automation.

Comment: Thanks.  I had stumbled onto this as well.  This method will work in powershell also, but I ended up doing it in C#, and even found a class library to allow for the same automation with Firefox: [link](http://watin.org/)